# Setting RewriteBase from an environment variable in .htaccess

Tags: bash, apache, environment

I'm trying to create a dynamic RewriteBase that is set via an environment variable but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried:

```
RewriteBase env('URL_PATH')
RewriteBase %{ENV:URL_PATH}
```

but neither have worked.

For a bit more information as to why I'm doing this the site that will be using this dynamic RewriteBase will be installed in a subdirectory with the same value as the `URL_PATH` variable. That will then get called by a parent service calling it at the URL variable.

So calling this URL:

```
example.com/my-subdirectory
```

Will resolve my site in the following directory:

```
/var/www/html/my-subdirectory
```

If there's another way to do this I'm all ears. Thanks.